# SVG градиент не работает при подключении через use

Tags: html, xml, svg, кроссбраузерность, svg-спрайт

У меня есть svg-файл с текстом, к которому применяется градиент:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 25.709 9.6739998" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>

    <linearGradient id="brand-text_gradient">
      <stop stop-color="#0a7800" offset="0" />
      <stop stop-color="#0a7800" offset=".52" />
      <stop stop-color="#ffd700" offset="1" />
    </linearGradient>

  </defs>
  <g id="main">

    <text x="-0.12919067" y="7.5240645" font-weight="bold" font-size="10px" font-family="Roboto" line-height="1" white-space="pre" fill="url(#brand-text_gradient)">test</text>

  </g>
</svg>
```

Если открыть его как отдельный файл, он отображается корректно. Однако когда я подключаю его на страницу, заливка становиться полностью прозрачной. При этом если вместо градиента указать простой цвет, все работает. Подключаю следующим образом:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 25.709 9.6739998">
  <use xlink:href="/assets/svg/custom/text.svg#main"></use>
</svg>
```

Проверял в firefox, chrome, opera последних версий. Работает только в firefox.

**UPD**: Не работают не только градиенты, но и в принципе все "невидимые элементы". Т.е. маски, фильтры, `defs` и т.п.. В консоли браузера они не отображаются.

**UPD**: Также в консоли webkit-браузеров не отображаются недопустимые элементы. Т.е. если я вставлю в `g#main` что-то вроде `<asd></asd>`, то этот элемент браузер не увидит.

Comment: @MaximLensky , Мне нужна возможность менять svg через css. Вариант с object для этого не подходит.

Comment: @MaximLensky , И? Проблемы есть, я пытаюсь их решить. Раньше я использовал спрайты через "symbol" на странице, и это работало. Теперь хочу перейти на внешние спрайты, т.к. они имеют ряд преимуществ. Все современные браузеры должны поддерживать данную фичу.

Comment: А xml'ный префикс и все нужные неймспейсы прописаны в файле?

Comment: @Qwertiy , Я выше написал все содержимое svg-файла. Больше там ничего нет. Пробовал добавлять и убирать `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. Не помогает.

Comment: Попробуй `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` и вроде ещё один namespace должен быть для xlink, но пока не нашёл.

Comment: @Qwertiy , Все пробовал. Прописывал `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` как в файле, так и снаружи. Вообще никакого эффекта.

Comment: @MaximLensky , Мне нужно наследовать некоторые стили в svg, например чтобы изменить заливку при наведении на внешний элемент. Object этого делать не позволяет.

Comment: @MaximLensky , И с symbol тоже ничего не работает

Comment: мне просто интересно ... почему нельзя вставить ваши иконки прямо в html ?

Comment: @MaximLensky , Я же сказал, внешние спрайты имеют преимущества. Например, браузер спокойно кэширует внешние svg-файлы, и этот кэш не зависит от html. При этом их можно стилизовать через css, как и спрайты на html-странице.

Comment: а через js вставить не вариант ?

Comment: @MaximLensky , Суть в том, что я не ищу костылей, я пытаюсь использовать вроде-как-уже-стандарт, который должен нормально работать во всех браузерах. Должен. Но не работает.

Comment: тогда получается что задача останется не решённой ?

Comment: @MaximLensky , Пока что так. В течении месяца мне в любом случае придется ее решить. Или перейти на старый способ использования спрайтов.

Comment: хотя вставить через js и делать обычный hover это не костыль

Comment: Если вдруг станет интересно то скачайте архив и посмотрите реализацию: [not use.rar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uj9uiysbeo9xxwo/Not%20use%20not%20marker%20not%20symbol.rar) и это будет работать там где use не поддержимается и не работает symbol

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте исключить секцию `<defs>`
Градиент пока не применен, его можно не прятать, а именно это делает `<defs>`

А также пробуйте обернуть весь код групповым тегом `<g>`

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 25.709 9.6739998" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 
<g id="main">
    <linearGradient id="brand-text_gradient">
      <stop stop-color="#0a7800" offset="0" />
      <stop stop-color="#0a7800" offset=".52" />
      <stop stop-color="#ffd700" offset="1" />
    </linearGradient>

    <text x="-0.12919067" y="7.5240645" font-weight="bold" font-size="10px" font-family="Roboto" line-height="1" white-space="pre" fill="url(#brand-text_gradient)">test</text>

  </g>
</svg>
```

**Update**

> Если вы вызываете спрайт, который расположен локально, на вашем ПК, то
> браузеры на движке webkit, в целях безопасности не воспроизводят
> локальный файл. А, у Firefox с этим всё в порядке. Когда перенесёте
> файл SVG на сервер, то будет работать везде –

Загрузил файл `text.svg`на сервер и теперь файл с градиентами виден во всех браузерах

```html
 <img src="https://svg-art.ru/files/text.svg" width="20%" height="20%" />   

<h2> Добавлено с помощью img </h2>

<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svg-art.ru/files/text.svg" width="20%" height="20%" >
   
</object> 

<h2>  Добавлено с помощью object </h2>
```

update  14.02.2021
Проверка на файле, внутри которого скрипт выводящий размеры

```html
 <img src="https://svg-art.ru/files/imgdummy.svg" width="20%" height="20%" /> 
 <h2> Добавлено с помощью img </h2>
 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svg-art.ru/files/imgdummy.svg" width="20%" height="20%" >
   
</object>  
<h2>  Добавлено с помощью object </h2>
```

Comment: Если убрать `defs`, но градиент оставить за пределами `g`, вообще перестает где-либо отображаться. Если же обернуть все в `g`, ничего не меняется: все так же видно в firefox, и не видно в остальных браузерах. Также, в консоли chrome и opera вообще не отображается градиент как элемент, т.е. только `g`, в котором `text`.

Comment: @Ikor Jefocur Ещё нюанс. Если вы вызываете спрайт, который расположен локально, на вашем ПК, то браузеры на движке webkit, в целях безопасности не воспроизводят локальный файл. А,  у Firefox с этим всё в порядке. Когда перенесёте файл SVG на сервер, то будет работать везде

Comment: Локальный файл бы в принципе не нашёлся по абсолютному пути, так что вряд ли.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT , У меня все расположено на сервере и грузится по http. Также, нет никаких ворнингов в консоли браузера по поводу безопасности. Webkit-браузеры как будто просто не видят градиент.

Comment: @Ikor Jefocur В моем крайнем примере я загрузил ваш SVG файл на свой сервер и вызываю его несколькими способами. Градиенты видны во всех современных браузерах. Видимо проблемы у вас на сервере или в верстке, к сожалению решить их можете только вы сами.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> fill="url(#brand-text_gradient)"
> ```

Используй полный путь к файлу

```
fill="url(/assets/svg/custom/text.svg#brand-text_gradient)"
```

Comment: Сделал. Теперь не работает еще и в firefox.